# A property of unimodal sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, inequalities, reference-request

It is well-known that $(-1)^j \sum_{i=0}^j (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} \geq 0$. This inequality can be used to prove Bonferroni's inequalities for example.  Recently I noticed that a similar inequality applies to non-negative unimodal sequences with alternating zero sum: if $a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \ldots \leq a_k \geq a_{k+1} \geq \dots \geq a_{n}$ with $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i a_i = 0$ then $(-1)^j \sum_{i=0}^j (-1)^i a_i \geq 0$ for $j=0 \ldots n$. Of course the binomial sequence is just a special case.  My question is if anyone has any knowledge of this property of unimodal sequences having appeared or having been used anywhere in the literature?  Thanks.

Jose A Rodriguez

Answer (score 6):

Closely related ideas come up in discrete Morse theory too, in proving the Morse inequalities.

You can prove your inequality combinatorially by a sign-reversing involution argument, i.e. a type of matching argument, as follows.  Make a graded partially ordered set with $a_i$ elements at rank $i$, i.e. in the $i$-th level of the poset, for each $i$.  Now include all possible edges between ranks $i$ and $i+1$ for each $i$.  I am assuming the $a_i$'s are integers, but you can do a weighted version otherwise.

Greedily start at rank $0$, taking each element of rank $i$ for $i < k$ which hasn't already been matched with an element of rank $i-1$ and matching it with an element of rank $i+1$. Likewise, start at rank $n$ and proceed downwards through the poset, greedily taking element of rank $n-i$ for $n-i > k$ which hasn't already been matched with an element of rank $n-i+1$ and matching it with an element of rank $n-i-1$.  When we get to rank $k+1$, we must only match with those elements of rank $k$ that weren't already matched with elements of rank $k-1$.  The fact that the alternating sum is 0 tells us we can get a complete matching this way.

Now we can interpret $(-1)^j\sum_{i=0}^j (-1)^i a_i$ as the number of elements at rank $j$ that have been matched with elements at rank $j+1$, so in particular as a nonnegative integer.  To see this, assign weight $+1$ to each element at rank $j$ or at any other rank of the same parity as $j$; assign weight $-1$ to the elements whose rank differs from $j$ by an odd number.   The alternating sum you consider is now the sum of the weights for ranks $0$ to $j$.  Each matching edge completely contained in the lowest $j$ ranks contributes 0 to this alternating sum, whereas each element of rank $j$ that is matched with an element of rank $j+1$ contributes 1 to this alternating sum.

I agree with Vladimir that this is a very nice observation you've made!

Answer (score 3):

For $k=0$ (a decreasing sequence), the proof is more or less the key idea that makes [Leibniz convergence test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) work, for instance. Since the total alternating sum is zero, you are always reduced to the case $k=0$ (if you go past the mode, you can replace your sum with the "better half" of the total alternating sum), so it is not much of a generalisation. It's a very cute observation though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm digging out an old post...

Does anyone know a reference for the property enunciated by Jose A Rodriguez in 2012?

I thought it was a well-known properties of unimodal sequence. Nevertheless, Louis Comtet does not speak about it in his books "Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions" (1974). Nor are Knuth, Patashnik and Graham in "Concrete Mathematics" (1988)

Thanks for the help